# Tailoring Windows store app for Fair

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a app that will be available at a regional fair and the public will use it to quickly download "perks" to theirs pen-drives. BUT when you move your mouse to the top-right corner of the screen a "menu" appears (there's a similar thing on tablets) and it enables the user to quit/switch-out-of my app, and that I can't allow! How do I block that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait for Windows 8.1 i.e. 18th October. 8.1 offers such thing to manage. Moreover it also offers [kiosk mode](http://www.winbeta.org/news/windows-81-kiosk-mode-lets-you-automatically-launch-app-login). Through which you can allow only one app to be open on top most.

[image]

[Source](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-charms-bar-in-windows-8-with-the-windows-8-1-upgrade)

Comment: I don't want to sound rude but is this a confirmed feature? where can I check that?

Comment: Yes, it's confirmed. You can download Windows 8.1 Preview from [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-8/preview-download)

Answer (score 0):

This is not under the control of your application, it's a feature of the operating system. And as far as I know, there's no way to block it. Typically such changes would be done through group policy settings, but at least in Windows 8, there's no such control available. I'm not sure about Windows 8.1, although I haven't stumbled upon any mention of such features there, either.

Also, this is not the only way for the user to switch out of your application. He could also drag the app down from the top and close it or go to the lower bottom corner to open the start screen, if he's using the mouse. The keyboard would give him even more options, of course.